# SelectList with SelectListGroup

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to return a `SelectList` with `<optgroup>`'s using `SelectListGroup`, but the code below only returns the values in the SelectList without the groups. How can I have my select list separated by groups?

```
public SelectList MyList()
{
   var group1 = new SelectListGroup() { Name = "Group 1" };
   var group2 = new SelectListGroup() { Name = "Group 2" };

   var items = new List<SelectListItem>();

   items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Item 1", Group = group1 });
   items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Item 2", Group = group2 });

   return new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text");
}
```

Comment: You create `List<SelectListItem>` with groups, but then throw it away by creating and returning a new `SelectList`. Change the method to `public List<SelectListItem> MyList()` and `return items;`

Comment: Thanks for your help. It still doesn't show my groups in the list though.

Comment: That should work fine. What is actually happening, and how are you using it in the view?

Comment: I'm setting it equal to a ViewBag. So `ViewBag.MyList = theDb.MyList();`. Then in my view I'm trying to use it like this `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.MyList)`

Comment: If you used the code in my first comment, then its `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.MyList)` - you not returning `SelectList` - your returning `List<SelectListItem>`

Answer (score 24):

I find this method works, which uses a strongly-typed approach:

**View model:**

```
public class PageViewModel
{
    public int SelectedDropdownItem { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DropdownList { get; set; }
}
```

**Example entity model (for this example):**

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
// Get list for the dropdown (this uses db values)
var entityList = db.Entity.ToList();

// Define the Groups
var group1 = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Active" };
var group2 = new SelectListGroup { Name = "Allowed" };

// Note - the -1 is needed at the end of this - pre-selected value is determined further down
// Note .OrderBy() determines the order in which the groups are displayed in the dropdown
var dropdownList = new SelectList(entityList.Select(item => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = item.Name,
    Value = item.Id,
    // Assign the Group to the item by some appropriate selection method
    Group = item.IsActive ? group1 : group2
}).OrderBy(a => a.Group.Name).ToList(), "Value", "Text", "Group.Name", -1);

// Assign values to ViewModel
var viewModel = new PageViewModel
{
    // Assign the pre-selected dropdown value by appropriate selction method (if needed)
    SelectedDropdownItem = entityList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsDefault).Id,
    DropdownList =  dropdownList
};
```

**View:**

```
<!-- If needed, change 'null' to "Please select item" -->
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.SelectedDropdownItem, Model.DropdownList, null, new { @class = "some-class" })
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Using "Group.Name" as the `dataGroupField` for the `SelectList` constructor was piece I was missing.  Thanks for the good example.

Answer (score 0):

If you have dynamically groups, you have to use 'foreach' because SelectListGroup is working with references.

```
foreach (var group in groups)
{
   foreach (var item in items.Where(i => i.Group == group))
   {
      var selectItem = new SelectListItem
      {
         Name = item.Name,
         Value = item.Value,
         Group = group
      };
   }
}
```